# Iterate over JSON dictionaries (Bing API)

Tags: python, json, bing-api

I'm trying to pull all of the `DisplayUrl` values out of JSON returned by the Bing API. I am not sure what I'm doing wrong. Any insight is appreciated!

```
search_response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
search_results = search_response.read()
results = json.loads(search_results)
for item in results.get(u'Web', []):
     print item.get(u'DisplayUrl')
```

My request is configured to return two results so I'm looking to get two prints from the `DisplayUrl` key.

The received `results`:

```
{
    u'd': {
        u'results': [
            {
                u'Web': [
                    {
                        u'Description': u'Test.comprovidesacompletesoftwaresolutionforcreatingonlinetestsandmanagingenterpriseandspecialistcertificationprograms,
                        inupto22languages.',
                        u'Title': u'Test',
                        u'Url': u'http: //www.test.com/',
                        u'__metadata': {
                            u'type': u'WebResult',
                            u'uri': u"https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Data.ashx/Bing/Search/v1/ExpandableSearchResultSet(guid'51264a7c-1d14-44a2-bbcc-afa43e7fac29')/Web?$skip=0&$top=1"
                        },
                        u'DisplayUrl': u'www.test.com',
                        u'ID': u'6987b446-c20a-4521-a998-f7cf62cff0aa'
                    },
                    {
                        u'Description': u"Test your Internet Connection with Speakeasy's reliable and accurate broadband speed test. What's your speed?",
                        u'Title': u'SpeakeasySpeedTest-MegaPath',
                        u'Url': u'http: //www.speakeasy.net/speedtest/',
                        u'__metadata': {
                            u'type': u'WebResult',
                            u'uri': u"https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Data.ashx/Bing/Search/v1/ExpandableSearchResultSet(guid'51264a7c-1d14-44a2-bbcc-afa43e7fac29')/Web?$skip=1&$top=1"
                        },
                        u'DisplayUrl': u'www.speakeasy.net/speedtest',
                        u'ID': u'b2cab0a5-9866-481b-86aa-1621616ca9c9'
                    }
                ],
                u'VideoTotal': u'',
                u'RelatedSearch': [

                ],
                u'Image': [

                ],
                u'__metadata': {
                    u'type': u'ExpandableSearchResult',
                    u'uri': u"https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Data.ashx/Bing/Search/v1/Composite?Sources='web'&Query='test.com'&$skip=0&$top=1"
                },
                u'ImageOffset': u'',
                u'AlterationOverrideQuery': u'',
                u'ImageTotal': u'',
                u'WebTotal': u'707000000',
                u'SpellingSuggestionsTotal': u'',
                u'WebOffset': u'0',
                u'Video': [

                ],
                u'News': [

                ],
                u'AlteredQuery': u'',
                u'SpellingSuggestions': [

                ],
                u'VideoOffset': u'',
                u'NewsTotal': u'',
                u'ID': u'51264a7c-1d14-44a2-bbcc-afa43e7fac29',
                u'NewsOffset': u''
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an outer wrapping to traverse here; your `results` object is a dictionary with one key `'d'`, referencing a dictionary value which has a `'results'` key, and that is a list of dictionaries, and *there* we find a dictionary with the `'Web'` key finally:

```
for result in results['d']['results']:
    for item in result.get('Web', []):
        print item.get(u'DisplayUrl')
```

Demo:

```
>>> for result in results['d']['results']:
...     for item in result.get('Web', []):
...         print item.get(u'DisplayUrl')
... 
www.test.com
www.speakeasy.net/speedtest
```

Comment: no luck. I tried making the Results lower-case since thats the way it is in the JSON but still nothing.

Comment: @ChrisHall: can you give us a *sample* of the JSON you are receiving please? Edit your question.

Comment: @ChrisHall: What we are going on is the documentation, which clearly states `results['Web']` is a dictionary with a `'Results'` key, the latter a list. But if your query is returning some different JSON I'd like to see that.

Comment: the if statement is never actually entered, even though 'Web' is in the results:

Comment: @ChrisHall: do `print results` and post that output.

Comment: getting error msg:    for item in results['d']['results'].get('Web', []):
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get'

Comment: @ChrisHall: yup, I still misread the format, already corrected and demo added.

Answer (score -1):

It's more nested than it looks like.

Here's a sample json output from the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd250846.aspx):

```
"Web":{
            "Total":5100,
            "Offset":0,
            "Results":[
               {
                  "Title":"Testign part 2 - Tiernan OTooles Programming Blog",
                  "Description":"If this works, it means nothing really, but i have managed to build a .TEXT blog posting app. could be handy if i move my main blog to .TEXT, which i am thinking about..",
                  "Url":"http:\/\/weblogs.asp.net\/tiernanotoole\/archive\/2004\/09\/24\/233830.aspx",
                  "DisplayUrl":"http:\/\/weblogs.asp.net\/tiernanotoole\/archive\/2004\/09\/24\/233830.aspx",
                  "DateTime":"2008-10-21T05:08:05Z"
               }
```

Notice that `DisplayUrl` is inside a list, stored with the `Results` key. So, to get it:

```
for item in results.get('Web'. {}).get('Results', []):
        print item.get('DisplayUrl', "Not Found")
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: No joy. API documentation is doesn't appear to cover the parsing, only the sending of the request.

Comment: @aIKid: Try running your code with `results = {}`; you'll get an attribute error now.